# 'HessPattern' not working in matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I've this struct for setting up a solver for an optimization problem:

```
option = optimoptions(@fminunc,...
    'Display','iter','GradObj','on','MaxIter',30,...
    'ObjectiveLimit',10e-10,'Algorithm','quasi-newton','HessPattern',sparseH);
```

Such setting seems fine to me, but when I run my solver with a call

`[P, FVAL, INFO, OUTPUT, GRAD, HESS] = fminunc (@myFunc,X0(:),option);`

(Literally the next call), I get the error

```
Requested 254016x254016 (480.7GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may
take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.
```

However my `sparseH` is

```
>> whos sparseH
  Name              Size                   Bytes  Class     Attributes

  sparseH      254016x254016            87043112  double    sparse
```

Moreover if I set `trust-regions` instead of `quasi-newton` the algorithm run. Although for small inputs I can actually see `quasi-newton` is faster.

Am I setting something wrong?

For a better check I did

```
>> A = sparseH(1:100,1:100);
>> sum(A(:))

ans =

   (1,1)      880

>> size(A)

ans =

   100   100

>>
```

So I have less than 1000 ones, in a submatrix with a total of 10000 entries. Also in total

```
>> sum(sparseH(:))

ans =

   (1,1)        5313186

>> prod(size(sparseH))

ans =

   6.4524e+10

>>
```

Comment: @Adriaan sure? the `HessPattern` parameter is there to explicitly tell what is the sparsity of the Hessian

Comment: Can you show what `sparseH` looks like? If it is all `1`, then this is the expected behavior. What is its sparsity?

Comment: See the update, it seems fine to me.

Comment: Indeed it looks good. I have no idea what is wrong. Sidenote:  the sparsity is generally given in `%`, so you can easily compute it as `nnz(sparseH)/prod(size(sparseH))*100`.

Comment: Is there a way to check if a given field in the option data structure is set?

Comment: Humm good thinking. When I explore the `option` returned by your first call, I see no reference to `HessPattern`, I don't know why

Comment: OH wait,  I know. `HessPattern` is an option *only* for trust-region type algorithms. I think quasy newton types need the full Hessian

Comment: Ah, so my guess was correct. I thought `quasi-newton` methods used hessians as well, or at least an approximation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: It appears that a quasy-newton approach would need the entire Hessian matrix and that `HessPattern` is only available for trust-region type of algorithms.

Indeed the quasy-newton approach is a faster algorithm, but it is common that faster algorithms need higher memory and often very big problems can only be solved with simpler optimization, by waiting longer (e.g. Neural Networks are just solved using gradient descend-type algoritms)